# How to assign / copy a Boost::multi_array

Tags: c++, boost, boost-multi-array

I want to assign a copy of a boost::multi_array. How can I do this. The object where I want to assign it to has been initialized with the default constructors.

This code does not work, because the dimensions and size are not the same

```
class Field {
  boost::multi_array<char, 2> m_f;

  void set_f(boost::multi_array<short, 2> &f) {
    m_f = f;
  }
}
```

What to use instead of `m_f = f` ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should resize `m_f` before assigning. It could look like in the following sample:

```
void set_f(boost::multi_array<short, 2> &f) {
    std::vector<size_t> ex;
    const size_t* shape = f.shape();
    ex.assign( shape, shape+f.num_dimensions() );
    m_f.resize( ex );
    m_f = f;
}
```

May be there is a better way. Conversion `short` to `char` will be implicit. You should consider using `std::transform` if you want explicit conversion.

Comment: really ? boost does not provide any way of doing this in one line ? two at most ?

Comment: @rodrigob, that’s right. The logic at the time was to avoid “surprise” allocations. Of course this is a fatal flaw since arrays are then not true value types (since some assignments are forbidden).  That was, in part, why I had to write my own array library https://gitlab.com/correaa/boost-multi