# C++ multidimensional arrays possibilities

Tags: c++, arrays, matlab, c++11, boost

I would like to translate some existing Matlab code that quite naturally uses a lot of multidimensional arrays and I wonder what are the possible options. I want the containers to have copy constructors, default constructors, if possible clear error messages at compilation, access via `A[i][j]` and in general not to be troublesome. Preferably, they should use the `std::move` operation for speed.

As far as I can see the options boils down to:

- `std::vector` iterated. It sure works, but it seems stupid to write `std::vector<std::vector<std::vector<double> > >`for a 3D array. I am also concerned with the overhead in speed and memory.
- The [boost::multiarray](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/libs/multi_array/doc/) and [blitz::Array](http://blitz.sourceforge.net/) offer most of the functionality but fails at the copy constructor (see [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1237723/how-to-assign-copy-a-boostmulti-array)) at runtime. It is unclear to me if there are valid reasons for that.
- The [Eigen](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/) library seems to be very fast but it does not allow copy at all, and has no default constructor, which means that another container has to be used.
- The `std::array` has the disadvantage that the size has to be known when the object is created, so there is no default constructors.

Is there a simpler multidimensional container satisfying all the requests but more frugal than iterated `std::vector`?

Comment: Who said the Eigen library doesn't support copies at all?

Comment: http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox-devel/classEigen_1_1Array.html#ad9f6f2c9890092e12fd3344aa6ffcbd1, http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox-devel/classEigen_1_1Array.html#aa1ef64a2517d538e03b71584369e14bb

Comment: At least with `boost::multi_array`, you do get better locality than with `vector<vector<vector<double>>`, even if copy is apparently broken. As always, there's writing your own?

Comment: *[...] blitz::Array [...] fails at the copy constructor [...]. It is unclear to me if there are valid reasons for that.* To my understanding it's because Blitz was developed before move-semantics came up. Blitz arrays have a weird mix of value/reference semantics. The copy-ctor creates a reference, whereas the assignment operator does a copy. In a way this emulates move-semantics. E.g. construct an array in a function and initialize another array with the function's return value. This won't copy, just increment and then decrement a ref-count. (Ignoring elision)

Comment: I indeed ended up writing the container that I wanted. For `eigen` my first try was unsuccessful and so I assumed there was a good reason for the absence of copy constructor. Thanks, I will look further at eigen even though it does not have multidimensional arrays, only matrices.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure this can answer all your needs but I myself had to handle multi-dimensional arrays for creating meshes/grid and wanted to create my own class for that.
My class let's call it *MultiArray* uses a a one-dimension vector as container.

For instance, writing *MultiArray<4, float, 10, 15, 10, 18> A()* would create a multi array A[10][15][10][18] in a vector of size 10*15*10*18.

I can access to elements by single index *A(i)* or by coordinates A[i][j][k][l] by calling *A({i,j,k,l})*. For performance purpose I have precomputed in the constructor the product of the dimensions in order to compute fastly  coordinates->index or index->coordinates.

The code is generic for N dimensions. I can detail some parts if you want.

Answer (score 1):

There is good linear algebra package called Armadillo

http://arma.sourceforge.net/

used it with R, happy user

Answer (score 0):

You have missed another option:

- std::valarray

Depending on what your requirements are it could be useful.
http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/valarray/