How to delete the first rows/columns in a boost::multi_array?
It is very easy to delete the last rows or columns in a boost::multi_array, for example, using the following minimal example:
#include "boost/multi_array.hpp"
#include <iostream>

typedef boost::multi_array<double, 2> array_type;

// Helper function for printing arrays
void print_array(const array_type& A){
  for ( size_t i=0; i < A.shape()[0]; i++ ) {
    for ( size_t j=0; j < A.shape()[1]; j++ )
      std::cout << A[i][j] << " ";
    std::cout << std::endl;
  }
}

int main () {
  
  // Create a 2D array that is 5 x 3
  array_type A(boost::extents[5][3]);

  // Assign values to the elements
  int values = 0;
  for(size_t i = 0; i < A.shape()[0]; ++i) {
    for(size_t j = 0; j < A.shape()[1]; ++j) {
        A[i][j] = values;
    }
    values++;
  }

  // Print the array
  std::cout << "A:" << std::endl;
  print_array(A);

  // Delete rows and print the array again
  A.resize(boost::extents[3][A.shape()[1]]);
  std::cout << std::endl << "A after resizing:" << std::endl;
  print_array(A);
  
  return 0;
}

(https://godbolt.org/z/TMocoqrnd)
This code produces the following output:
A:
0 0 0 
1 1 1 
2 2 2 
3 3 3 
4 4 4 

A after resizing:
0 0 0 
1 1 1 
2 2 2 

As one can see, the resize operation simply deleted the last rows of the array.
Question: Would it be possible to delete the first rows (or columns) instead, such that the output of the program would become
A:
0 0 0 
1 1 1 
2 2 2 
3 3 3 
4 4 4 

A after resizing:
2 2 2 
3 3 3 
4 4 4 


You create a new array and copy/move the data to it. That's a basic exercise. It's not natively supported because it is a slow operation.

@ALX23z thank you very much for your comment! I was thinking resize would be very effective compared to creating a new array and copying the data. Also, consider the case that the array is very large and creating a new array to move the data over could exceed the memory limits.

You have the same problem as with std::vector. While you can avoid new allocation, the operation will take a lot of time. Vector stores pointer to origin, size, and capacity. A data structure that can have front elements erased quickly would require more fields and a completely different and more complicated management.

@ALX23z thank you very much for the info. Is there another solution than to copy the array? Maybe one can reverse the order along one dimension, then resize and then reverse the order again? Or something similar? The array is huge in my application (~1e10 entries).

All of these operations require the movement of all the array's data. Tried using a viewer to multi-subarray instead? Like std::span but for a multi_array? There's boost::multi_array_ref, but I am not certain it's the most convenient way.

@ALX23z thank you very much! multi_array_ref does not allow to resize the array. Thus it is not useful for me. A view is nice but it also does not resize the array but it just gives you a view. I need to actually resize the array keeping only the last rows, the other rows must be deleted. I start to think boost::multi_array is not the right tool for me. I am, however, surprised because it seems like a really obvious task to remove some rows or columns from an array data structure. And I'm not even asking to remove any rows, but just the first ones that sit next to each other in memory.

Using a different library (of mine), A = +A({2, 5}, {0, 3}); which ultimately it is the same as A = +A.dropped(2);. The + is important to break the aliasing of A in the LHS and RHS. https://godbolt.org/z/MaMqofddG (don't expect to be more --or less-- efficient than other answers here; it is just more straightforward).

To avoid the copy you can use a view:
  // print skipping 2 rows
  using boost::indices;
  using boost::multi_array_types::index_range;
  auto B = A[indices[index_range(2,5)][index_range(0,3)]];
  std::cout << std::endl << "A after resizing:" << std::endl;
  print_array(B);

Which prints Live On Coliru:
A:
0 0 0 
1 1 1 
2 2 2 
3 3 3 
4 4 4 

A after resizing:
2 2 2 
3 3 3 
4 4 4 

Of course, index_gen is is wildly more versatile. Also if you want you can avoid the base array in the first place using multi_array_ref:
Live On Coliru
int main () {
  std::array<double, 15> raw {
    0,0,0,1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3,4,4,4
  };
  array_type A(raw.data(), boost::extents[5][3]);

  std::cout << "A:" << std::endl;
  print_array(A);

  array_type B (raw.data () + 6, boost::extents[3][3]);
  std::cout << std::endl << "B:" << std::endl;
  print_array(B);
}

Printing
A:
0 0 0 
1 1 1 
2 2 2 
3 3 3 
4 4 4 

B:
2 2 2 
3 3 3 
4 4 4 


Using origin() you can use a hybrid approach as well: https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/609ec273a50fd87d

Hi @sehe thank you very much for your answer! This is, however, not really a solution to the question, since it does not resize the array A but instead it creates another array B that is a resized version of A.

The hybrid solutions do in fact create a new instance of the same statical type without any copying. It sounded like you could use that

Hi @sehe, I tried that, but I was not able to assign the new array B to the old array A because of the size mismatch. Maybe I missed something, but so far I was not able to use these methods to obtain a satisfying solution.

@TMueller83 You're quite right. Sadly it turns out you run into variations of https://stackoverflow.com/q/1237723/85371 being down to operator= only supporting element-wise copy from the same shape "This performs an element-wise copy of x into the current multi_array_ref." (see also preconditions). My best counter-shot at this would require optional<multi_array_ref> to distinguish reseating from assignment

Here's what that looks like: https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/ec92f0e1da889547 - the good news is that std::optional does retain triviality of most operations (e.g. static_assert(std::is_trivially_copyable_v<std::optional<int>>)). However, there's some cost in usage complexity still

Hi @sehe, thank you very much for your solution! In the mean time I stepped away from boost::multi_array. It just seems to be not the right tool for me. In the end I made my own array class using std::vector as underlying storage. It was pretty easy, I dont understand why boost::multi_array is so limited and cumbersome. Thank you very much anyways!

@TMueller83 I think the problem is that multi_array is way too flexible and they had to make kinda weird concessions to avoid unpleasant surprises. Which, ironically, introduces inflexibilities precisely around identity/assignment semantics. I think there's a standard proposal for md_span or something that should be a lot more evolved.

@TMueller83, I wrote an alternative that doesn’t have the limitation on assignment. However you still have to be careful with aliasing: https://gitlab.com/correaa/boost-multi#copy-and-assigment-and-aliasing
